# how to get the python type of variable correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cant get the type?  I am using python3.

```
print(type(base64_type))
# output: <class 'bytes'>

if type(base64_type) is 'bytes':
    print('wow')
else:
    print ('Why are we not working')
```

Comment: Try `isinstance`?

Comment: `<class 'bytes'>` isn't the same thing as `'bytes'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'bytes'` is a string
Meanwhile, `bytes` is a class.

```
>>> bytes
<class 'bytes'>
>>> isinstance(b'foo', bytes)
True
```